# What is the proper way to append an array inside another array in scala

Tags: scala

I try to append an array element inside another array dynamically(by query result) as follows.But the element does not append in the array.
What is the proper way to append an array inside another array?

```
var content:Array[Array[String]]=Array(Array())

content(0)=Array("h1","h2","h3","h4","h5","h6","h7","h8","h9")

val myResult = for(ts <- myQueryList) yield (
    content+:Array(e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6,e7,e8,e9)
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the operation creates a new array that you need to reassign to `content` like this:

```
content=content+:Array(e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6,e7,e8,e9)
```

or a little bit cleaner:

```
content ++= Array(e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6,e7,e8,e9)
```

I hope this is what you want, it's not too clear what you want to do from your code.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason you don't want to use `Array.concat`?

Something like:

```
myResult = Array.concat(content, myQueryList)
```

(Provided `myQueryList` is an `Array[Array[String]]`).